# The number of way to distribute n indistinguishable balls into k indistinguishable boxes arbitrarily

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

[image]

Before even attempting at the proof, I need a clarification of a point in the question. I don't understand how the $k$ in $k \geq \lambda_1\geq ...\geq \lambda_r\geq 1$ is relevant. For $n=7$ and $k=3$, for example, isn't $\{1,5,1\}$ a valid multiset of ball distribution, but $(5,1,1)$ is not a valid integer partition of 7, since $\lambda_1 = 5 > 3 = k$?

Also, to prove the statement, I'm thinking of setting up a bijection between the set of ball distributions and the set of integer partitions of n. Would this be a sensible approach?

Comment: The number of partitions of $n$ into at most $k$ parts is equal to the number of partitions of size at most $k$.  In a [Ferrers diagram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FerrersDiagram.html)  you can count the dots by rows, or by columns.

Comment: Could you please explain the first sentence? As an example, why doesn't the tuple (5,1,1) above work?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand how the $k$ in $k \geq \lambda_1\geq ...\geq \lambda_r\geq 1$ is relevant. For $n=7$ and $k=3$, for example, isn't $\{1,5,1\}$ a valid multiset of ball distribution, but $(5,1,1)$ is not a valid integer partition of 7, since $\lambda_1 = 5 > 3 = k$?

It seems that you are misunderstanding something.

For $n=7,k=3$, the number of the former is $8$ since we have $\{7,0,0\},$$\{6,1,0\},$$\{5,2,0\},$$\{5,1,1\},$$\{4,3,0\},$$\{4,2,1\},$$\{3,3,1\},$$\{3,2,2\}$. The number of the latter is $8$ since we have $(3,3,1),$$(3,2,2),$$(3,2,1,1),$$(3,1,1,1,1),$$(2,2,2,1),$$(2,2,1,1,1),$$(2,1,1,1,1,1),$$(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)$. So, the number of the former is equal to the number of the latter as claimed.

---

To see why they have the same number, let us take again the case where $n=7,k=3$.

$\quad\qquad$[image]
The above shows :

- $\{7,0,0\}$ in the former corresponds to $(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)$ in the latter.
- $\{6,1,0\}$ in the former corresponds to $(2,1,1,1,1,1)$ in the latter.
- $\{5,2,0\}$ in the former corresponds to $(2,2,1,1,1)$ in the latter.
- $\{5,1,1\}$ in the former corresponds to $(3,1,1,1,1)$ in the latter.
- $\{4,3,0\}$ in the former corresponds to $(2,2,2,1)$ in the latter.
- $\{4,2,1\}$ in the former corresponds to $(3,2,1,1)$ in the latter.
- $\{3,3,1\}$ in the former corresponds to $(3,2,2)$ in the latter.
- $\{3,2,2\}$ in the former corresponds to $(3,3,1)$ in the latter.

In the former, we count the number of balls "vertically". In the latter, we count the number of balls "horizontally".

This explains why they have the same number.

Comment: I.e.: place horizontal separators in the boxes (like floors in a bulding) and tilt horizontally the whole stack. Then the number of boxes $k$ becomes the limit of balls at each floor, and the limit on floors (unrestricted here) becomes the number of horizontal boxes (the $r$).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find a bijection to send a multiset $\{a_1,a_2,\dots, a_k\}$ where $\sum a_i = n$ to a partition $(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r)$ where $\sum \lambda_r = n$ and $3\ge\lambda_1\ge\dots\ge\lambda_r\ge 1$.

In your example, $\{1,5,1\}$ is a valid multiset and (5,1,1) is a partition, but (5,1,1) is not the partition that your bijection is supposed to send to. The problem does not say that the bijection is to send each multiset to the same partition using the elements in the multiset. You need to find a bijection so that it works.

Here's a hint: Using your example, {1,5,1} = {5,1,1} is a multiset, we will map it to (3,1,1,1,1), which is a partition of n=7 into parts of size at most k=3.

```
     1 *
     5 * * * * *
     1 *
       3 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score -1):

$n=\lambda_1+\lambda_2+ \ldots+\lambda_r$ corresponds to a partition of $n$ into $r$ parts. The condition $k \ge \lambda_i$ indicates that each part has size at most $k$.

Note that the question refers to number of partitions of $n$ into parts of *size at most* $k$. So $\{5,1,1\}$ is not the partition we're looking for with $n=7,k=3$ since there is one part (i.e. $5$) that has size greater than $3$. For example, with $n=7,k=3$, $\{3,2,1,1\}$ is a valid partition.

The condition $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \ldots \ge \lambda_r$ means that we don't have to care about the **order** of the parts when counting number of partitions. For example, $\{3,2,1,1\},\{3,1,1,2\}$ and $\{3,1,2,1\}$ are considered to be one partition $\{3,2,1,1\}$ for $n=7,k=3$. Why do we need this condition? Try to look back the situation with indistinguishable boxes. Do we have to care about the order of the boxes?

> Also, to prove the statement, I'm thinking of setting up a bijection between the set of ball distributions and the set of integer partitions of n. Would this be a sensible approach?

Yes, bijection is the way to go. Before finding the main bijection, you should "translate" these two situations into one language. In particular, since the balls and boxes are indistinguishable, the number of distributions of $n$ indistinguishable balls into $k$ indistinguishable boxes is the same as number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts.

Comment: What I’m asking is, what does that condition $\lambda_i \leq k$ have to do with the distribution of balls into boxes? A distribution with 5 balls in 1 box, 1 ball in another box and 1 ball in yet another box is certainly a valid way to put 7 balls into 3 boxes, but why is its corresponding integers partition of 7, i.e. (5,1,1), not valid? Wouldn’t the condition $\lambda_i \leq k$ then exclude some cases from the set of integer partitions of n (and hence we wouldn’t have a desired bijection)?

Comment: Well, if you want to go with balls and boxes instead of integer partition: The condition $\lambda_i \le k$ indicates that each box must have at most $k$ balls. So even though $\{5,1,1\}$ is a valid partition for the first situation (where we talk about balls and boxes), it is not a valid partition for the second situation with integer partition where $n=7,k=3$ since $5>3$.

Comment: My current assumption is that, if we say that a bijection exists, then for each distribution of balls we would find a corresponding integers partition. Also I assume that the integers partition (5,1,1) corresponds to the distribution 5 balls - 1 ball - 1 ball, yet the way integers partition is defined in the question somehow forbids tuples like (5,1,1)? What would the tuple corresponding to the abovementioned balls distribution be?

Comment: To be even more explicit, if F is the bijection from the set of balls distributions to the set of integers partitions, what is F(5 balls, 1 ball, 1 ball)?

Comment: By answering this question of your, I think it will give away too much about the solution (which you can easily search on google). You should first spend some time finding a bijection. Try to take some small examples of $n,k$, list all the distributions/partitions for each situation then try to give a mapping between the two. See if you find any pattern that you can generalize for any $n,k$.

Comment: Say we have 3 balls and 2 boxes. Then 1 way to distribute the balls into boxes would be 3 balls in one box and 0 ball in another box, and another scenario would be 2 balls in one box and 1 ball in another box. But if we try to find the integers partitions of 3 with the specification that $k = 2 \geq \lambda_1 \geq ... \geq \lambda_r \geq 1$, then the only one we can find is (2,1). So there can’t be a bijection between the 2 sets. Am i missing something here?

Comment: There's another integer partition of $3$, which is $\{1,1,1\}$ (i.e. when $r=3$).